ROS RPM question
We've been developing code using various ROS RPM packages found here: http://packages.ros.org/ros2/rhel. I noticed that most of the packages include .so files in them, for example:
$ rpm -ql ros-humble-ament-index-cpp | grep "\.so"
/opt/ros/humble/lib/libament_index_cpp.so

Our code builds against those .so files. However those packages don't specifically Provide those .so files, for example:
$ rpm -q --provides ros-humble-ament-index-cpp
ros-humble-ament-index-cpp = 1.4.0-2.el8.20240728.203705
ros-humble-ament-index-cpp(x86-64) = 1.4.0-2.el8.20240728.203705
ros-humble-ament-index-cpp-devel = 1.4.0-2.el8.20240728.203705
ros-humble-ament-index-cpp-doc = 1.4.0-2.el8.20240728.203705
ros-humble-ament-index-cpp-runtime = 1.4.0-2.el8.20240728.203705

Because of this, we're having trouble DNF installing our homemade packages. DNF fails to resolve the ROS dependencies, so we're seeing this:
nothing provides libament_index_cpp.so()(64bit) needed by ourPackageName-0.0.1-1.el8.x86_64

Despite the ROS packages being properly installed. Is this normal?
